# How to bind the checked attribute dynamically usnig jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var array = data.d[i].WebDisplayValues.split(",");
var checkBoxValues = data.d[i].CustomFieldValue.split(",");
item += "<td class='chk' style='width:40%;'>";
for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {                         
    item += "<input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' class='chk' name='chkCustom' tabindex='0'><label>" + array[j] + "</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
```

array = [M,F,U]
checkBoxValues = [M,F]

From the above code I am binding my checkboxes dynamically, below is the HTML that rendered on the webpage:

```
<input id="checkbox" class="chk" type="checkbox" tabindex="0" name="chkCustom" disabled="">
<label>M</label>
<input id="checkbox" class="chk" type="checkbox" tabindex="0" name="chkCustom" disabled="">
<label>F</label>
<input id="checkbox" class="chk" type="checkbox" tabindex="0" name="chkCustom" disabled="">
<label>U</label>
```

My requirement is I also want to set the property **checked** of the checkbox with respect to checkBoxValues that is [M,F].

So when the web opens the M and F checboxes comes with checked and the third comes with unchecked.

Comment: Add the checked attribute whenever it is needed `<input type="checkbox" checked class="...` By the way, id has to be unique according to HTML spec `:/`

Comment: BTW ids got to be unique within a document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
   var txt=$(this).next('label').text();
   if(txt=='M' || txt == 'F') {
       $(this).prop('checked',true);
   }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/32tUD/)

Comment: I can't use "this" as here this indicates to some other button.

Comment: I want to use my "checkboxid" in place if "this". But when I am doing this change I am unable to get my require result

Comment: `this` indicates `current object` and in `$.each()` of `$(':checkbox')` it will point to current `checkbox` not any `other button`

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```
$('label:contains(M), label:contains(F)').prev(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXVd8/)

Comment: @user3124690 yes absolutely.